# How do I download a file from an FTP server using FTP over SSL using .NET?

Tags: .net, ftp, ftps

My post title almost states it all: How do I download a file from an FTP server using FTP over SSL using .NET? I have read a bit and there are several 3rd party components to purchase that wrap up this functionality.

The deal is, this is a very specefic need and is not going to grow much, so if downloading a file from an FTP server using FTP over SSL can be done using the .NET Framework (i.e. System.Net namespace or something), then that would be best.  I don't need a ton of functionality, but if for some reason coding against a secure FTP server is a nightmare or not doable through the .NET Framework BCL that would be nice to know, as a 3rd party .dll might be best.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://...");
request.EnableSsl = true;
using (var response = request.GetResponse()) 
using (var data = response.GetResponseStream()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I need to pass crededntials -> do I use a "request.Credentials = New Net.NetowrkCredential("user", "pass")" ? Also, I was given a host of sftp.domain.com and when using the code you provided it states it is "an invalid URI" (however I can get to it via a FTP/SFTP client application outside of .NET so I know the URI is valid). If I try "sftp://domain.com" I get an "The URI prefix is not recognized" exception. Any ideas on these (2) items?

Comment: I have a feeling SFTP is not supported via the FtpWebRequest class according to this link: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/181054/add-support-for-ftps-and-sftp-uris-for-webrequest

Comment: @atconway: Try the URI, `ftp://sftp.domain.com`.

Comment: That gave me: "The requested URI is invalid for this FTP command."

Comment: @atconway: In order to execute a command, you need a path, not just a domain name.  (eg, `ftp://sftp.domain.com/SomeFile`)

Comment: Yes that got me closer.  I am now getting this error: "The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access)."  I 'can' get to this file using FTP client software using the same credentials.  Any ideas on this?

Comment: @atconway: I don't know; compare the requests in a network monitor. Also, check the path and method.

Comment: Yeah got the 550 error solved! I turned on tracing in the web.config to look at the FTP traffic and like the FTP client software, the path to myFiles/Folder1/ is where the files exist. However that path is also the default path when connecting via code to the ftp domain. Therefore, adding that path in again in the URI request actually resulted in looking for myFiles/Folder1/myFiles/Folder1/ which is obviously not correct.  So just placing the filename directly after sftp.domain.com/myfile.txt worked. I added the final code for downloading a file thanks to your help SLaks for getting me started

Answer (score 4):

Here is the final VB.NET code I used:

```
    Dim request As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(New Uri("ftp://sftp.domain.com/myFile.txt")), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile
    request.EnableSsl = True
    request.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password")
    request.UsePassive = True
    Dim response As System.Net.FtpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), System.Net.FtpWebResponse)
```

Full details here:

**Download FTP Files Using FTP Over SSL (SFTP) in .NET:**
http://allen-conway-dotnet.blogspot.com/2010/11/download-ftp-files-using-ftp-over-ssl.html

Answer (score 0):

If you need some more features like **implicit SSL**, hash verification, or just cleaner syntax you can use [Ftp.dll FTP/FTPS client](http://www.lesnikowski.com/ftp/):

```
using(Ftp ftp = new Ftp())
{
    ftp.Connect("ftp.server.com");                       
    ftp.Login("user", "password");

    ftp.ChangeFolder("downloads");
    ftp.Download("report.txt", @"c:\report.txt");

    ftp.Close();
}
```

Please note that this is a commercial product and I'm the author.